# 1980s novel series about teens in Georgia who learn magic

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm trying to find a series of books I read in the 1980s about a group of teenage friends living in (I think) rural Georgia. They somehow encounter supernatural forces, maybe drawn from Native mythology, and at least one of them (the protagonist) learns magic. At some point in one of the books the teens make magic staffs for themselves. I think there were maybe three books in the series, perhaps more. I don't think they were marketed as YA books.

Ring any bells for anyone?

Comment: The country Georgia, or the region within a North American country?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was the David Sullivan books from Tom Deitz -- *[Windmaster's Bane](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1611876869)* was the first one.

> RIDDLE, RING, AND QUEST
> In Georgia’s Blue Ridge Mountains, tales are told of strange lights, of mysterious roads…of wondrous folk from enchanted realms. All these are hidden from mortal men, and those who have the gift to look on them are both blessed and doomed…
> THE WINDMASTER
> Young David Sullivan never dreamed that the myths of marvels and magic he loved were real. But in his blood was the gift of Second Sight. And near his family’s rural farm lay an invisible track between worlds…where he would soon become a pawn in the power game of the Windmaster, an evil usurper among those the Celts called the Sidhe. David’s only protection would be a riddle’s answer and an enchanted ring…as he began his odyssey of danger into things unknowing and unknown…

Comment: Excellent! Don't forget to accept your self answer in two days.

Comment: Even though you are answering your own question, this is still not a great answer.  you should still explain how the book in fits with your initial question, with quotes or at least links where possible.

Comment: @Xavon_Wrentaile That was my intent, but by the time I came back to clean the answer up, my question had correctly been marked as a dupe.